# What is the purpose to add a @ to get a ttribute in groovy

Tags: groovy

I find one use case today with groovy like this:

```
manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
```

It adds a *@* before the attribute, what is the purpose for that?

I test it in my local place, and I don't find big diff between we have *@* and without *@*.

My example is as follows:

```
class Person {
    private String hello;
}

def person = new Person()
person.hello = "hello world"

println person.@hello
```

Br,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used to access the field directly (without getter), see:

```
class Person {
    private String hello

    public String getHello() {
        "lol $hello"
    }
}

def person = new Person()
person.hello = "hello world"

assert person.@hello == 'hello world'
assert person.hello == 'lol hello world'
```